# Magento automatic order status - getting list of order_status / state

Tags: events, magento, model, status

I am trying to build a Magento module that observes certain events and tries to proceed automatically to a new automatic status/state, based on payment method.
In order to do that, I organized some status on the backoffice based on payment method. For example:

event: `sales_order_place_after`
Automatic status: `pp_1_pending` - First status/state where a new placed order will automatically have this status if the payment method is paypal.

event: `sales_order_payment_pay`
Automatic status: `pp_2_payment` - Second status/state after an order is payed when the payment method is paypal

event: `sales_order_invoice_save_after`
Automatic status: `pp_3_complete`- Third and final status/state after an order is invoiced, ending the transaction.

For this to work I would need to collect all status with the prefix pp_ and after checking which was set on the order, proceed to the next status in order. This way this module would be scalable.

However I can't seem to get the status collection. I am trying:
`$statuses = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')

            ->getCollection()

            ->addAttributeToSelect('status')

            ->addAttributeToSelect('label')

            ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('like','pp_'));`

Hope anyone can help me. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **addAttributeToSelect()** function is used for EAV based models.For flat models use **addFieildToSelect()**

The code should be

```
$statuses = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToSelect('status')
->addFieldToSelect('label')
->addFieldToFilter('status',array('like'=>'pp_%'));
```

Comment: Thanks but can't get no data :/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the generated SELECT query if it looks ok.

```
$collection->getSelect()->__toString();
```

Comment: This works with sales/order_status! But not with sales/order_status_state.

Comment: It delivers the sql string.

Comment: in case someone is wondering, to get both states and status together, here's a function for you:  
`private function _allStatusStateCollection($filter) {  
 $collection = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order_status' )  
        ->getCollection()->joinStates();  
     if ($filter != '') { return $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status',array('like'=>$filter.'%')); }  
    return $collection;  
    }  `

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the wildcard (%) in your query, because you want the statuses that **begin** with pp_:

```
$statuses = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')  
        ->getCollection()  
        ->addAttributeToSelect('status')  
        ->addAttributeToSelect('label')  
        ->addFieldToFilter('status',array('like','pp_%'));
```

Answer (score 0):

in case someone is wondering, to get both states and status together, here's a function for you:
`private function _allStatusStateCollection($filter) {

    $collection = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order_status' )

              ->getCollection()->joinStates();

        if ($filter != '') { return $collection->addFieldToFilter('main_table.status',array('like'=>$filter.'%')); }

    return $collection;

    }`